# Python regular expression for mysqldump inserts

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I have a bunch of queries in string format like that:

> INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1,'pb',NULL,'User
>   Example','example@example','','da',1493878226,NULL,NULL,'das','unassigned','','','','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',1,0,0,25495,NULL,'','',0,0,0,'',NULL,''),(2,'pb',NULL,'User
>   Example','example@example','','a774f',1493878226,NULL,NULL,'device','unassigned','','','','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',0,0,0,NULL,NULL,'','',0,0,0,'',NULL,''),(3,'p=',NULL,'User
>   Example','example@example','','95fa',1493878226,NULL,NULL,'device','b','','','','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',0,0,0,NULL,NULL,'','',0,0,0,'',NULL,''),(4,'pa',NULL,'User
>   Example','example@example','','ea1',1493878226,1510178200,NULL,'a','unassigned','','','','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',0,0,0,NULL,NULL,'','',0,1,0,'',NULL,''),(5,'pb',NULL,'AAA','example@example','','das',1493878226,NULL,NULL,'a','unassigned','','','dasmin.png','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',0,0,0,NULL,NULL,'','',0,0,0,'',NULL,'');

And what I want to do is to be able to separate each portion of separated text by () so that I can iterate over them, change some things and then do a manual insert.

What should I do?

I'm not good at regular expressions by the way ...

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a bit of work with Python and SQL so I think I know what you are trying to do.  Try this:

```
import re

sql_text = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'pb',NULL,'User Example','example@example','','da',1493878226,NULL,NULL,'das','unassigned','','','','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',1,0,0,25495,NULL,'','',0,0,0,'',NULL,''),(2,'pb',NULL,'User Example','example@example','','a774f',1493878226,NULL,NULL,'device','unassigned','','','','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',0,0,0,NULL,NULL,'','',0,0,0,'',NULL,''),(3,'p=',NULL,'User Example','example@example','','95fa',1493878226,NULL,NULL,'device','b','','','','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',0,0,0,NULL,NULL,'','',0,0,0,'',NULL,''),(4,'pa',NULL,'User Example','example@example','','ea1',1493878226,1510178200,NULL,'a','unassigned','','','','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',0,0,0,NULL,NULL,'','',0,1,0,'',NULL,''),(5,'pb',NULL,'AAA','example@example','','das',1493878226,NULL,NULL,'a','unassigned','','','dasmin.png','','','','',1,'',NULL,'',NULL,'','','','',0,0,0,NULL,NULL,'','',0,0,0,'',NULL,'');"
sql_list = re.findall("\([^)]+\)", sql_text)
for sql_item in sql_list:
    print(sql_item)
```

I take the SQL text, and regex each set of values into a list.  The regex itself is the key, it's a negative character class.  It matches each opening paran up to and including the next closing paran.  The [^)]+  means all non closing parans.

Clearly instead of printing (sql_item) you'll be looking to change the text, but this should be enough to get you going.

Here is a good site to play with regexes:
https://www.regex101.com

Comment: What if there is `(` or `)` in the middle of a value, e.g. `query="INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'pb',NULL,'User),( Example','example@example', ..."`

Comment: There isn't in the example, but I see what you are saying.  You could check the length list created, and if it's correct you are good to go.  If not try something like splitting on: ),(   I'd try it before I over engineer a solution.  Working with regexes is often trial and error.

Comment: Great! It works like a champ, thanks, really appreciate. :)

Comment: Great! @user202890  If you could mark the answer as accepted and vote it up (the check mark next the the answer and up arrow) that would be super.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you need each of the insert values set separately, you can try the following:

```
import re
values = re.findall(r'(\(.*?\))', query) #this would match the '(' and ')' too
values = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', query) #if you don't want to capture the braces
```

The regex would find the patterns between `(` and `)` with the use of a `.*`. `?` to make the search non greedy. otherwise the `.*` would match till the last `)`

Comment: What if there are `(` or `)` in the middle of a string, e.g. `query="INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'pb',NULL,'User),( Example','example@example', ..."`